# Nested case statement in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, case, oracle12c

I have been staring at this for the last couple of hours and I don't see where I'm throwing off this query, the code has been anonymized so forgive the replacement identifiers:

```
select count (distinct(case when status not in ('Larry','Curly','Moe','Shemp')
                       then case when(case when 
                       (MIN(case when status in ('Larry','Curly','Moe','Shemp')
                            then case when to_char(my_date,'YYYY') = 1900
                            then my_dttm
                            else my_dttm
                            end
                            end) <= '18-nov-2019')
            and
                       (MIN(case when status in ('Larry','Curly','Moe','Shemp')
                            then case when to_char(my_date,'YYYY') = 1900
                            then my_dttm
                            else my_dttm
                            end
                            end) >= '1-oct-2019')
            then
                        MIN(case when status in ('Larry','Curly','Moe','Shemp')
                            then case when to_char(my_date,'YYYY') = 1900
                            then my_dttm
                            else my_dttm
                            end
                            end)end) is null
           then case when to_date >= '1-oct-2019' and from_date <= '18-nov-2019' then c_id end
)) from my_table; -- error code references this line
```

The error code I'm getting : ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword". I searched this site for something similar but I haven't been able to find anything that fits my specific situation. Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This looks very complicated and wrong. Inside your aggregation function `COUNT` you are trying to deal with row values (`status`, `c_id`, `to_date`, `from_date`) and aggregations (`MIN(…)` at the same time. This cannot work. What exactly are you trying to achieve? It seems you want to select `c_id` if a particular condition is met. Which?

Comment: By the way: Even when anonymizing a query, different columns should be different columns, same columns same columns. `case when ... then my_dttm else my_dttm end` is just `my_dttm`, so the whole `case when` makes no sense anymore.

Comment: On a side note: You are mistakenly using string literals where you want date literals. This will crash your query, when running it with other session settings. This: `to_date >= '1-oct-2019'` should be this: `to_date >= date '2019-10-01'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing two `END` keywords at error line.

See the following:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE
        WHEN STATUS NOT IN(
            'Larry', 'Curly', 'Moe', 'Shemp'
        ) THEN CASE
            WHEN(CASE
                WHEN(MIN(CASE
                    WHEN STATUS IN(
                        'Larry', 'Curly', 'Moe', 'Shemp'
                    ) THEN CASE
                        WHEN TO_CHAR(MY_DATE, 'YYYY') = 1900 THEN MY_DTTM
                        ELSE MY_DTTM
                    END
                END) <= '18-nov-2019')
                    AND(MIN(CASE
                    WHEN STATUS IN(
                        'Larry', 'Curly', 'Moe', 'Shemp'
                    ) THEN CASE
                        WHEN TO_CHAR(MY_DATE, 'YYYY') = 1900 THEN MY_DTTM
                        ELSE MY_DTTM
                    END
                END) >= '1-oct-2019') THEN MIN(CASE
                    WHEN STATUS IN(
                        'Larry', 'Curly', 'Moe', 'Shemp'
                    ) THEN CASE
                        WHEN TO_CHAR(MY_DATE, 'YYYY') = 1900 THEN MY_DTTM
                        ELSE MY_DTTM
                    END
                END)
            END) IS NULL THEN CASE
                WHEN TO_DATE >= '1-oct-2019'
                     AND FROM_DATE <= '18-nov-2019' THEN C_ID
            END -- this is missing in your code
        END -- this is missing in your code
    END))
FROM
    MY_TABLE;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: This just fixes the syntax errors, however the logic is completely nonsense (`WHEN ... THEN MY_DTTM ELSE MY_DTTM` or compare `FROM_DATE` with string literal)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I am attempting to replicate a calculation in Tableau which a colleague wrote and this is the logic that works. The my_dttm field can be null...

Comment: If you compare a `DATE` value with `<= '18-nov-2019'` then result will be wrong e.g. for `9-nov-2019` - provided the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is properly set by coincidence.

Comment: @Tejash Thanks for your help and after fixing an issue with GROUP BY the query actually returned the correct result set...

Answer (score 0):

Following two case statements didn't have "end"

`select count (distinct(case when status not in ('Larry','Curly','Moe','Shemp')
                       then case when(case when 
                       (MIN(case when status in ('Larry','Curly','Moe','Shemp')
                            then case when to_char(my_date,'YYYY') = 1900
                            then my_dttm
                            else my_dttm
                            end
                            end) <= '18-nov-2019')
            and
                       (MIN(case when status in ('Larry','Curly','Moe','Shemp')
                            then case when to_char(my_date,'YYYY') = 1900
                            then my_dttm
                            else my_dttm
                            end
                            end) >= '1-oct-2019')
            then
                        MIN(case when status in ('Larry','Curly','Moe','Shemp')
                            then case when to_char(my_date,'YYYY') = 1900
                            then my_dttm
                            else my_dttm
                            end
                            end)end) is null
           then case when to_date >= '1-oct-2019' and from_date <= '18-nov-2019' then c_id end
end
end
)) from my_table;`

```
case when status not in ('Larry','Curly','Moe','Shemp')
then case when(case when
```